# How do you change the opacity of error bars in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to change the opacity of the erro bars to alpha=0.5 in this example:

```
ggline(desfactorial, x = "Water_added", y = "PCR", color = "Solvent",
       add = "mean_sd", size=1,
       palette = c("#009E73", "#E69F00", "#0072B2"), 
       xlab = "Water added / g",
       ylab ="Protein-carbohydrate ratio", legend="right", error.plot = "errorbar") + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(desfactorial$PCR, na.rm=TRUE),linetype='dotted', col = 'grey', size=1)+
theme(axis.text=element_text(size=20), axis.title=element_text(size=20,face="bold"), legend.title=element_text(size=20, face="bold"),legend.text=element_text(size=20))+     scale_x_discrete(labels = scales::label_parse())
```

[image]

I would like to know if there is a way to add in the erro.plot the desired alpha value. Here is the dataframe I am working with:

```
desfactorial <- data.frame(
  Solvent = factor(c(
    "Water", "Water", "Water", "Water", "Water", "Water", "Water",
    "Water", "ChCl:2Gly", "ChCl:2Gly", "ChCl:2Gly", "ChCl:2Gly",
    "ChCl:2Gly", "ChCl:2Gly", "ChCl:2Gly", "ChCl:2Gly", "ChCl:2Urea",
    "ChCl:2Urea", "ChCl:2Urea", "ChCl:2Urea", "ChCl:2Urea", "ChCl:2Urea",
    "ChCl:2Urea", "ChCl:2Urea", "ChCl:2Urea", "ChCl:2Urea", "Water",
    "Water", "Water", "Water", "Water", "Water", "ChCl:2Gly", "ChCl:2Gly",
    "ChCl:2Gly", "ChCl:2Gly", "ChCl:2Gly", "ChCl:2Gly", "ChCl:2Urea",
    "ChCl:2Urea", "ChCl:2Urea", "ChCl:2Urea"
  )),
  Water_added = factor(
    c(
      "0", "0", "3", "3", "6", "6", "20", "20", "0", "0", "3", "3",
      "6", "6", "20", "20", "0", "0", "3", "3", "6", "6", "20", "20",
      "45", "45", "10", "10", "30", "30", "45", "45", "10", "10", "30",
      "30", "45", "45", "10", "10", "30", "30"
    ),
    levels = c("0", "3", "6", "10", "20", "30", "45")
  ),
  PRY = c(
    5.1476543701677, 5.24206405872243, 5.38853875361231, 5.54209197950729,
    5.59692261420859, 5.33758024267941, 6.35605594568486, 6.11398365482863,
    5.6275477119015, 5.55850593100969, 6.56805384213524, 6.71367492865504,
    6.82559818297811, 7.04188813664945, 7.90352355877037, 8.24946798339131,
    7.22111750906, 6.8410364885922, 6.98847106262559, 7.29277790286923,
    8.80926606615939, 8.92784511466374, 10.0114247638609, 9.40760655480343,
    8.32376937032233, 8.52028563666514, 6.16362677140164, 6.22644550947947,
    6.50077762048591, 6.34718054340683, 5.79605607812372, 6.26225533957947,
    6.93671532060051, 7.87123213762398, 7.51694018439269, 8.06930986110173,
    8.42323297518708, 8.22990329914185, 8.95475913956326, 8.35304817442309,
    8.2430160707796, 8.28151339125548
  ),
  CRY = c(
    11.5646290023399, 11.9638056665846, 12.2101627720237, 12.12285427245,
    12.155046705445, 11.8170692856966, 12.1250520787855, 12.4769641088183,
    10.4098577086808, 10.0544782849387, 11.3132581407265, 11.9730393450593,
    12.1133712743981, 11.6130134011753, 12.6426813224131, 12.1306042501626,
    11.6526145416142, 10.7116583486815, 11.7765361401332, 11.8823371989241,
    12.4227694735619, 12.0000292939802, 13.7043627792218, 12.4865426127152,
    12.8966146437781, 13.1792533796986, 12.3812896168193, 12.7271148582088,
    11.8381098438314, 11.952576146431, 12.2907792592306, 12.2551976925363,
    11.7625448257849, 13.1684808685182, 12.4333413472634, 12.9705340638451,
    13.1165857506246, 12.9864605632202, 12.4447925660838, 13.2160423711566,
    12.9029170459932, 13.2076320425397
  ),
  PCR = c(
    0.445120580100421, 0.438160248069201, 0.441315882042024, 0.457160653337395,
    0.460460806925684, 0.451683925483961, 0.524208548085801, 0.490021739383499,
    0.540597947578928, 0.552838822013882, 0.580562536489023, 0.560732720837958,
    0.563476345961934, 0.606379058852782, 0.625146150346991, 0.680054168223378,
    0.61969933728364, 0.638653350014123, 0.593423310510604, 0.613749448511659,
    0.709122557969639, 0.743985276697817, 0.730528294175045, 0.753419649184842,
    0.645422818331483, 0.646492285351297, 0.497817833372438, 0.489226786969987,
    0.549139829435973, 0.531030337363888, 0.471577591288264, 0.510987704702089,
    0.589729129481774, 0.597732738970799, 0.604579249812617, 0.622126261060802,
    0.642181825006251, 0.633729510752936, 0.71955873044987, 0.632038543751438,
    0.638849032462727, 0.627024841741654
  )
)
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: It´s pretty long, so I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came with a satisfactory answer in a rather simple code:

```
ggplot(desfactorial,aes(x=Water_added,y=PCR,color=Solvent))+
  geom_point(stat = 'summary', fun = mean,size=1)+
  geom_line(aes(color=Solvent,group=Solvent),alpha=1,stat = 'summary', fun = mean, size=1)+
  stat_summary(fun.data="mean_sdl", fun.args = list(mult = 1), geom="errorbar",  width = 0.2, size=1, alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = mean(desfactorial$PCR, na.rm=TRUE),linetype='dotted', col = 'grey', size=1)+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#009E73", "#E69F00", "#0072B2"))+
  theme_classic(base_size = 20) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=20), axis.title=element_text(size=20,face="bold"), legend.title=element_text(size=20, face="bold"),legend.text=element_text(size=20))+     scale_x_discrete(labels = scales::label_parse())+
  labs(y = "Protein carbohydrate ratio", x= "Water added / g")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't do it inside the `ggline` function, so I tried to create the lines and points separately:

```r
library(dplyr)

cols <- c("#009E73", "#E69F00", "#0072B2")
alpha_perc <- 60

desfactorial %>% 
  {
    mean_tmp <- summarise(., PCR = mean(PCR), .by = c(Solvent, Water_added))
    ggline(., x = "Water_added", y = "PCR", color = "Solvent",
       add = "mean_sd", size=1,
       xlab = "Water added / g",
       ylab ="Protein-carbohydrate ratio", legend="right", error.plot = "errorbar") + 
  geom_line(aes(color = Solvent, group = Solvent), data = mean_tmp, alpha = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Solvent, group = Solvent), data = mean_tmp, alpha = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(values =  paste0(cols,alpha_perc)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(desfactorial$PCR, na.rm=TRUE),linetype='dotted', col = 'grey', size=1)+
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=20)
        , axis.title=element_text(size=20,face="bold")
        , legend.title=element_text(size=20, face="bold")
        ,legend.text=element_text(size=20)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = scales::label_parse())
  }
#> Warning: Using `size` aesthetic for lines was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `linewidth` instead.
```

[image]

A simpler option would be to just change the linetype of the errobars with the `add.params` arg.

```r
ggline(desfactorial, x = "Water_added", y = "PCR", color = "Solvent",
       add.params = list(linetype = 2),
       add = "mean_sd", size=1,
       palette = c("#009E73", "#E69F00", "#0072B2"), 
       xlab = "Water added / g",
       ylab ="Protein-carbohydrate ratio",
       legend="right", 
       error.plot = "errorbar") + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(desfactorial$PCR, na.rm=TRUE),linetype='dotted', col = 'grey', size=1)+
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=20), axis.title=element_text(size=20,face="bold"), legend.title=element_text(size=20, face="bold"),legend.text=element_text(size=20))+     scale_x_discrete(labels = scales::label_parse())
#> Warning: Using `size` aesthetic for lines was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `linewidth` instead.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I am having some problems with the first code, the message says ```! Cannot add <ggproto> objects together
i Did you forget to add this object to a <ggplot> object?``` .

Comment: Sorry, forgot a '+' a the end of  `scale_color_manual` line. I have already edited the answer

Comment: I still don´t get the plot, now the error is ```Error in `geom_line()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 4th layer.
Caused by error in `FUN()`:
! object 'Solvent' not found``` .